# Extracting href from attribute with BeatifulSoup and save in to .xls

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
def get_add(soup):
    add_list=soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"jaddt"})
    #add_list = [i.find('a') for i in add_soup]
    add=[i.text for i in add_list]
    print add
    return add
```

Now problem is ,

i want to parse the data from the .html page where attributes is "class":"jaddt" ,which is containing "href" / for example "....read more"

currently using beautifulsoup but it's just parsing the data from above class only, i want to parse the data from "href" link even !

can any one help me ?

i mean , i want to parse and extract information from href , main problem is, object is bypassing the href

Comment: Can you clarify the question - what data do you want exactly? The link text? The link URLs? Do you have an example HTML fragment?

Comment: It sounds like you need to actually **request** the resource referred to in the `href` attribute.

Comment: Let me understand, what do you want is doing crawling of deeper pages?